# android application slow on higher end devices

Tags: android, performance

I have developed an application.The application is almost complete but  my issue is that my application runs perfectly on lower end devices like **samsung duos** ,**samsung ace**, **samsung s3** and **sony Experia LT18i** but on higher devices like **Sony Experia c6602** and **samsung s4** the application is slow on all the screens having scrolling.

I am not able to come to a reason why this should be like so. The app should have run better on higher end devices.

Comment: Enable/Disable Hardware acceleration - how's that set in your code?

Comment: Are the high-end devices running a different version of Android?

Comment: I am not using hard ware acceleration and the device os is 4.1.2(sony Experia c6602) on which the application slows down. It works fine on 4.0.4(samsung duos)

Comment: So you got this resolved? How if yes? @susheel

Comment: There were lot of reasons, first the lists were not using view-holder patterns, second data was being loaded to UI on main threads, unnecessary objects were getting created.. all this used to eat up the performance... used multiple tools to figure these out and then moved on..